# system differential equation 11

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

The system in the symmetric form is given by
$$\frac{dx}{x^2-y^2-z^2}=\frac{dy}{2xy}=\frac{dz}{2xz}.$$
Rewrite using the derivatives
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=x^2-y^2-z^2,$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=2xy,$$
$$\frac{dz}{dt}=2xz.$$

I think that
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{dz}{dt}$$
$$xy^2=xz^2+C1$$
$$\frac{dx}{x^2-y^2-z^2}=\frac{d(y+z)}{2x(y+z)}$$
I do not know what's next
may all my steps do not correct?

Comment: "I think that $\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{dz}{dt}$" Why would you think that? This seems wrong unless $y=z$, right?

Comment: I just assumed
I have no idea how to solve it
Сan you help me?

Answer (score 1):

From $\frac{dy}{2xy}=\frac{dz}{2xz}$, you have
$$ \frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dz}{z} $$
and hence $y=c_1z$. Put this in $\frac{dx}{x^2-y^2-z^2}=\frac{dz}{2xz}$ and then you have
$$\frac{dx}{x^2-(c_1^2+1)z^2}=\frac{dz}{2xz}$$
which can be written as
$$ \frac{dx}{dz}=\frac{x^2-(c_1^2+1)z^2}{2xz}.$$
The above equation is a homogeneous DE and you can solve by setting $x=uz$. I omit the detail.

Comment: if I thought that I got$$\frac{x^2}{z^2}+C1^2+1=C2/z$$
correct? and what to do next?